# Calculate a pixel value

Tags: c#

If I have this code in C#:

```
int index = 10;
float value = 20;

float* pixels = getPixelData();

pixels[index+1] = (byte)(value/256);
pixels[index+0] = (byte)(value & 0xFF);
```

Then, the question is how to calculate the 'value' if I have:

```
int index = 10;

pixels[index+1] = X;
pixels[index+0] = Y;

float value = ?
```

Comment: `pixels[index+0] + 256 * pixels[index+1]` ?

Comment: this (`value & 0xFF`), actually, will not work (until cast to int - `(int)value & 0xFF`); anyway, `value & 0xFF` just takes the lower byte. as soon as `256 * pixels[index+1]` will leave the lower byte empty, the `+ pixels[index+0]` will fill it again with the expected value

Comment: could you post the declaration of `pixels`?

Comment: @mizipzor yes, I just added the declaration of pixels!

Comment: @ie pixels[index+0] + 256 * pixels[index+1] will get very high values for pixels that are out of 255!

Comment: @olidev what do you mean by high values? and why pixels will be out of 255? `(int)value & 0xFF` will never produce value more then 255, `(byte)(value/256)` could be more then 255, but then the value should be also high. i'm I right?